# Websockets, Play Framework and Actor

Tags: java, ajax, playframework, websocket, actor

I need to inform all users about adding new **Record** to the database. 
So, I have the following code

1. Application.java - here I placed socket handler method

   ```
   public WebSocket<JsonNode> sockHandler() { 
       return WebSocket.withActor(ResponseActor::props);
   }
   ```
2. Then I opened the connection

   ```
   $(function() {
       var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
       var socket = new WS("@routes.Application.sockHandler().webSocketURL(request)")
       socket.onmessage = function(event) {
           console.log(event);
           console.log(event.data);
           console.log(event.responseJSON)
       }});
   ```
3. My Actor class

   ```
   public class ResponseActor extends UntypedActor {
       private final ActorRef out;
       public ResponseActor(ActorRef out) {
           this.out = out;
       }
       public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
           return Props.create(ResponseActor.class, out);
       }
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Object response) throws Exception {
           out.tell(Json.toJson(response), self());
       }
   }
   ```
4. And the last, as I think, I need to invoke the Actor from my Response Controller

   ```
   public Result addPost() {
       Map<String, String[]> request = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
       Response response = new Response(request);
       Map<String, String> validationMap =  ResponseValidator.validate(response.responses);
       if (validationMap.isEmpty()) {
           ResponseDAO.create(response);
           ActorRef responseActorRef =  Akka.system().actorOf(ResponseActor.props(outRef));
           responseActorRef.tell(response, ActorRef.noSender());
           return ok();
       } else {
           return badRequest(Json.toJson(validationMap));
       }
   }
   ```

My question is: what is `ActorRef` out and where can I get it in my Controller?
Could you please clarify the logic for sending update to all clients through web sockets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem, myself, though in Scala, so I'll see if I can assist based on what I've learned so far (I'm having my own problems with getting the message to my actor after the socket opens).

Accepting a WebSocket connection with an actor isn't done with the typical request/response model like making a GET request to the server for a page.  Instead, you need to use Play's WebSockets API:

```
import akka.actor.*;
import play.libs.F.*;
import play.mvc.WebSocket;

public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.withActor(ResponseActor::props);
}
```

The Play WebSockets documentation should be able to help you from there better than I can:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWebSockets